# Understanding linear algebra in Ordinary Least Squares derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

In ordinary least squared there is this equation (Kevin Murphy book page 221, latest edition)

$$NLL(w)=\frac{1}{2}({y-Xw})^T(y-Xw)=\frac{1}{2}w^T(X^TX)w-w^T(X^T)y$$

I am not sure how the RHS equals the LHS. Maybe my linear algebra is weak but I can't figure out how this happens. Can somebody point out how this happens. This is related to deriving the Ordinary Least squares equation where $\hat{w}_{OLS}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$